# Not able to integrate YouTube with our application using API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to integrate my web application with YouTube using API v3. We intend to upload videos to our specific YouTube channel. However, the login ID used uploads files to the default channel (provided by YouTube) instead of the default channel set in my login Id.

**Specific questions:**

1) What is a service account in this context?

2) Why are the videos being uploaded to YouTube default channel rather than default channel set in the account?

3) How can I upload videos to the user selected default channel (I am manager of this channel) via YouTube API v3?

We are running behind time on this integration, quick help is appreciated.

Look forward...

Comment: Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

A service account is

> "an account that belongs to your application instead of to an
>   individual end-user.  Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required." 
>   [[source](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount)].

YouTube API doesn't use service accounts, but you can use OAuth 2 flow to obtain a  refresh token, which could be reused indefinitely to make API calls without user interaction. Please see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth

Comment: You could also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457851/allowing-google-service-account-youtube-upload-access-via-api-v3

Comment: Thank you.. Please advice on the  following as well.. <br> 2) Why are the videos being uploaded to YouTube default channel rather than default channel set in the account?

3) How can I upload videos to the user selected default channel (I am manager of this channel) via YouTube API v3?