# Youtube data api - uploading video's to one channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, youtube-api

I'm assigned to create a node js app which is given to a few trusted people who need to submit videos. The budget is really small and they don't have the money for renting cloud storage.

Now I was wondering if it's possible to generate some sort of key and upload videos from a device to a single youtube channel. I searched the docs but could not find something relevant.

The users are internal and trusted, there is no way the app will be in someone else's hands.

Is this possible? If not, what are good alternatives?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 3):

In [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) repo, you have an example of youtube video upload code [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/youtube/upload.js) with the sample doc [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/youtube)

It uses [Youtube insert API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) used to upload a video to YouTube and sets video's metadata

Here is a minimal functional example (the authorization code need to be set manually in this example) :

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var querystring = require('querystring');
var url = require('url');

var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var FILENAME = '/home/user/test.mp4';

// get these from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials (don't forget to activate Youtube API)
var YOUR_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var YOUR_REDIRECT_URL = "https://your-domain/redirect";

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

// initialize the Youtube API library
var youtube = google.youtube({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client
});

// very basic example of uploading a video to youtube
function uploadVideo() {

    var req = youtube.videos.insert({
        part: 'id,snippet,status',
        notifySubscribers: false,
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                title: 'Node.js YouTube Upload Test',
                description: 'Testing YouTube upload via Google APIs Node.js Client'
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: 'private'
            }
        },
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(FILENAME)
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
        }
        if (data) {
            console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
        }
        process.exit();
    });

    var fileSize = fs.statSync(FILENAME).size;

    // show some progress
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        var uploadedBytes = req.req.connection._bytesDispatched;
        var uploadedMBytes = uploadedBytes / 1000000;
        var progress = uploadedBytes > fileSize ? 100 : (uploadedBytes / fileSize) * 100;
        process.stdout.clearLine();
        process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
        process.stdout.write(uploadedMBytes.toFixed(2) + ' MBs uploaded. ' +
            progress.toFixed(2) + '% completed.');
        if (progress === 100) {
            process.stdout.write('\nDone uploading, waiting for response...\n');
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, 250);
}

var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

var authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes.join(' ')
});

console.log("go to " + authorizeUrl + " to get authorization code");

var AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "X/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX";

oauth2Client.getToken(AUTHORIZATION_CODE, function(err, tokens) {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if (!err) {
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        uploadVideo();
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

If the user get the authorization code with the right channel, the video will be uploaded to that same channel

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using angular at client side, so require won't work here. Nevertheless this gave me a better insight. I'll let you know if it worked :)

Comment: If you want to call the api client side you have a Javascript example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples)

Comment: Yep, found it too :) Just confused on how to replace the google login button with my credentials.

Comment: You have a complete example [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.html) in youtube/api-samples github repo.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having a hard time trying to authenticate from code. the example has a google login button for a user, but I don't need that, i just want everything to be initialized at load because the user does not have to sign in

Comment: You have to provide an access token with the specified scopes to call that API. If you provide an existing valid access token, you can store it in your backend with a refresh token and call your backend from your client to retrieve it (securely). If the access token has expired, make your backend refresh it with the refresh token initially stored

Comment: that would work, but there is not an option for a backend service. Is there not a single way to do this all client side? even tho it might expose client secrets in source code (people who are using it are really trusted)

Comment: it seems you are looking for JWT token and service accounts, but unfortunately, till date, this feature is not supported , here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457851/allowing-google-service-account-youtube-upload-access-via-api-v3)

Comment: If I have multiple channels, where can I specify which channel to upload to?